# Full width child elements inside scrollable container

Tags: html, css

I have a div-container with a fix width and some child-elements witch could be bigger than the parent.

Is it possible to let all the child-elements take the full width of the scrollable area from the parent-element (`overflow: auto`)?

```css
#container {
    width: 200px;
    background-color: grey;
    overflow:auto;
    margin:10px;
}

#container p{
    display:block;
    background-color: green;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <p>Sample Text 1</p>
    <p>Sample Text 2</p>
    <p>A very very very very very long Sample Text</p>
</div>
```

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n6d2cung/). When you scroll to the right, you can see that the child-elements background-color is smaller than the content.

[image: childs are too small]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Wrap the content in a div, and set it to `display: inline-block`:

```css
#container {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: grey;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: 10px;
}

#container>div {
  display: inline-block;
}

#container p {
  display: block;
  background-color: green;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div>
    <p>Sample Text 1</p>
    <p>Sample Text 2</p>
    <p>A very very very very very long Sample Text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, this works for the large one, but I want to have all the child-elements with full width.

Comment: you mean, you want all th children to have the same width as the widest one?

Comment: Wow, thank you! It could be so easy, but I didn´t try to change the html-structure. +1

Comment: No Problem :D Sometimes, you have to change the HTML to get what you want

Comment: aaaaa I just spent hours on this! Finally found the right search terms to take me to this answer, thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

You could set the child elements to `display:table-row;`

```css
#container {
    width: 200px;
    background-color: grey;
    overflow: auto;
}
#container p {
    display: table-row;
    background-color: green;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <p>Sample Text 1</p>
    <p>Sample Text 2</p>
    <p>A very very very very very long Sample Text</p>
</div>
```

Add a extra `<div>` if you need extra controls for styling.

```css
#container {
    width: 200px;
    background-color: grey;
    overflow: auto;
}
#container div {
    display: table;
    border-spacing: 0 10px;
}
#container p {
    display: table-row;
    background-color: green;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div>
        <p>Sample Text 1</p>
        <p>Sample Text 2</p>
        <p>A very very very very very long Sample Text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use from absolute position property to do that .

```css
#container {
    width: 200px;
    background-color: grey;
    overflow:auto;
    margin:10px;
}
#container p{
    display:block;
    background-color: green;
    white-space: nowrap;
    position:absolute;
}
```